# php change type connection from odbc to PDO

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I used odbc connection to access to my DB, but I need to change it to PDO.

I access the DB with PDO without any trouble, but some sentences are refered to odbc and I don't know how to relate it to PDO.

On my code I just change the $connect to the pdo connection (it used to be the odbc

The last part of the php is the one that i need to adjust to pdo

```
<?php

function getArraySQL(){
$startd = "29964";
$endd = "29968";
$connect = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=projects;Database=dummy", "pass", "pass");
$query = "THIS IS THE QUERY";


if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;
};
$myarray = getArraySQL();
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

Comment: If you want to switch from ODBC to PDO, you shouldn't use the odbc_* functions anymore. Please use the methods of [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) instead.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know the equivalent functions on PDO. That's why I put the first part with PDO but I don't know how to turn the las part into PDO method

Comment: Please read the documentation of [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) first. There are also some examples in the comments.